# Passing a .go-file as additional argument to `go run`

Tags: go, command-line-arguments

For quick hacking, I prefer to use `go run prog.go ...` instead of building the executable first. However, the program I am working on should take another go-file as an argument. As a consequence, `go run` and the compiled binary behave differently:

```
go run prog.go foo.go
```

will try to execute both go-files, whereas

```
go build prog.go && ./prog foo.go
```

will correctly take my file as input (the intended behaviour). Now I can pass additional args like this `go run ... -- foo.go`, but then because of the `--` the position of the file differs in `os.Args` between the `go run prog.go -- foo.go` and the `./prog foo.go`. Any easy solution? I'd like to avoid having full flag-processing. Should I just give up and stick to the compiled version?

Comment: The fix to `go/cmd/run.go` would be very small; I recommend discussing it on the go-nuts list and submitting a CL. I don't see any way to really work around this.\

Comment: Given the minimal overhead of `go build prog.go && ./prog foo.go` compared to `go run prog.go foo.go` (which also compiles and links your program) I'd just stick to the "build" version.

Comment: Yeah; I use `go build` too most of the time because of all the problems with `go run`, but the really annoying thing IMO is that it writes an untracked file into your source directory. A good version of `go run` would definitely be worthwhile.

Comment: @RobNapier I just write it out somewhere else, like `go build -o /tmp/prog && /tmp/prog foo.go`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not possible. Here's the [source](https://golang.org/src/cmd/go/run.go#L71) for the command:

```
for i < len(args) && strings.HasSuffix(args[i], ".go") {
    i++
}
files, cmdArgs := args[:i], args[i:]
```

You can use `go install` instead of `go build`. That will put your executable in your `$GOPATH/bin` folder (I don't like having the binary in the same folder because sometimes I accidentally add it to git). But it's really not much different.

Another option you might want to consider is [`rerun`](https://github.com/skelterjohn/rerun). It will automatically recompile and run your code whenever you change a file:

```
rerun path/to/your/project foo.go
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at my problem again, I have to find out if I'm ever going to need several input files. If not, I might get away with just reading from `Stdin` instead of opening a file.